# How to install aquila library in visual studio

Tags: c++, git, visual-studio-2012, cmake, signal-processing

I want to install Aquila library in visual studio.

I clone the source from this [link](https://github.com/zsiciarz/aquila) and
using cmake create build files with visual stdio compiler then run ALL_BUILD visual stdio file and build it

but I didn't get include files what is the problem.(I think is's necessary to have include folder in this build directory)

Comment: The include files are probably in the source folder not the build folder. Is there an INSTALL target?

Comment: You can follow [this](http://nip-saga.blogspot.com/2015/06/configure-aquila-digital-signal-processing-libraray-visual-studio.html) tutorial this has A-Z steps how to configure Aquila in Visual studio

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the path of the libraries on your project properties?  `Project>Rightclick>properties>Debug` and there you have a field to add all the paths separated by ";"

You can add it like a relative path if you put it inside your project directory with  `PATH=%PATH%;$(ProjectDir)\YourDirectoriesUntilTheDll\`

Comment: I may be wrong but this seems to have nothing to do with the problem. The OP is building a library in Visual Studio with a project generated via CMake. After the build completed the OP wants to know where the include files are.

Comment: Srry maybe I understood u wrong. Have you check if the files are in the path it thinks? And that there are the files it needs? (No file missing or directory?)